# What is a working computer

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

What is a "working computer?"

1. A computer that works/ functions properly.
2. A computer that is made for working.
3. A computer that is working at the moment.

From a grammar standpoint,  I can think of three ways to interpret this phrase, as shown above. But I'm not sure which one applies in the following context:

> Even in the new computer labs that were created about 3years ago, you’ll hardly find a working computer.

And does the phrase always mean the same thing as it does here?

Comment: In the UK we would usually use _work computer_ for your second suggested meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may mean either of the three. It depends on the context.

In your example sentence, the meaning is "a computer that functions properly".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello, and welcome to ELL!!! When you write an answer, you need some information to support your answer, such as links to external resources. Please read [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) article about how to write a good answer.

Comment: +1 This clearly answers the question

Comment: @JamesK It does answer the question clearly, but without any supporting information

Comment: I'm not sure what supporting information you could add.  I suppose maybe some examples of "working computer" in other contexts.  Dictionaries just give "functioning or able to function"  but just quoting dictionaries does not an answer make. Especially as the dictionary definition does not answer this question "does it mean functioning or does it mean able to function in this context"